# how can i replace word1 with <span>word1</span>,word2 with <span>word2</span>,n with <span>n</span> using sublime RegEx?

Tags: html, regex

I need to replace each word in a sentence into a html tag including the word.how can i that?

Comment: You've been downvoted because this is a question about how to use regular expressions, which can be found pretty easily by searching online. Check out this source for example: https://dev.to/awwsmm/20-small-steps-to-become-a-regex-master-mpc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's no need to use regular expressions.

For example, we've got this sentence:

```
let sentence = "We love earth!";
```

Now, we'll put each word in an array by using the `split` method.

```
let array = sentence.split(" ");
```

Finally, we'll join the `<span>` to the beginning of each array's item and `<span>` to the end.

```
for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
   array[i] = "<span>" + array[i] + "</span>";
}
```